# Filter array of object with sub objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Apologies if there is already an answer for this, I've been unable to locate one that has worked for me.

I have defined a menu system for React where the information is stored in an array of objects.  Each object has the posibility of having sub items (objects in another array) and I'm looking to filter the entire menu for values.

`Menu Object`

```
[
  {
    "key": "Dashboard",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "title": "Dashboard",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/",
        "children": "Dashboard"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Clients",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Clients",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Clients.Add",
        "title": "Create Client",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Clients/create",
            "children": "Create Client"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Clients.List",
        "title": "List Clients",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Clients/",
            "children": "List Clients"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Clients.Search",
        "title": "Search Clients",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Clients/search",
            "children": "Search Clients"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Contractors",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Contractors",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Contractors.Add",
        "title": "Create Contractor",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Contractors/create",
            "children": "Create Contractor"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Contractors.List",
        "title": "List Contractors",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Contractors/",
            "children": "List Contractors"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Contractors.Search",
        "title": "Search Contractors",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Contractors/search",
            "children": "Search Contractors"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Jobs",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Jobs",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Jobs.Add",
        "title": "Create Job",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Jobs/create",
            "children": "Create Job"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Jobs.List",
        "title": "List Jobs",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Jobs/",
            "children": "List Jobs"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Jobs.Search",
        "title": "Search Jobs",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Jobs/search",
            "children": "Search Jobs"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isDivider": true
  },
  {
    "key": "Config",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Configuration",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Config.Category.Add",
        "title": "Create Category",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Category/create",
            "children": "Create Category"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Category.List",
        "title": "List Categories",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Category/",
            "children": "List Categories"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Specialist.Add",
        "title": "Create Specialist",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Specialist/create",
            "children": "Create Specialist"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Specialist.List",
        "title": "List Specialists",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Specialist/",
            "children": "List Specialists"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Status.Add",
        "title": "Create Status",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Status/create",
            "children": "Create Status"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Status.List",
        "title": "List Statuses",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Status/",
            "children": "List Statuses"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "UserManagement",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "User Management",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "UserManagement.Add",
        "title": "Create User",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/UserManagement/create",
            "children": "Create User"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "UserManagement.List",
        "title": "List Users",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/UserManagement/",
            "children": "List Users"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "isDivider": true
  },
  {
    "key": "LockScreen",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "title": "Lock Screen",
    "component": "Lock Screen"
  }
]
```

So if I were to filter this on title for the value "list" it should return back

```
[
  
  {
    "key": "Clients",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Clients",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Clients.List",
        "title": "List Clients",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Clients/",
            "children": "List Clients"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Contractors",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Contractors",
    "submenus": [      
      {
        "key": "Contractors.List",
        "title": "List Contractors",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Contractors/",
            "children": "List Contractors"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "Jobs",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Jobs",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Jobs.List",
        "title": "List Jobs",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Jobs/",
            "children": "List Jobs"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      
    ]
  },  
  {
    "key": "Config",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "Configuration",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "Config.Category.List",
        "title": "List Categories",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Category/",
            "children": "List Categories"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Specialist.List",
        "title": "List Specialists",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Specialist/",
            "children": "List Specialists"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "key": "Config.Status.List",
        "title": "List Statuses",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/Config/Status/",
            "children": "List Statuses"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "key": "UserManagement",
    "icon": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {},
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    },
    "isSubMenu": true,
    "title": "User Management",
    "submenus": [
      {
        "key": "UserManagement.List",
        "title": "List Users",
        "component": {
          "type": {},
          "key": null,
          "ref": null,
          "props": {
            "to": "/admin/UserManagement/",
            "children": "List Users"
          },
          "_owner": null,
          "_store": {}
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Or it should return back

```
[
  

  {
    "key": "Clients.List",
    "title": "List Clients",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Clients/",
        "children": "List Clients"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },
    
  {
    "key": "Contractors.List",
    "title": "List Contractors",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Contractors/",
        "children": "List Contractors"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },

  {
    "key": "Jobs.List",
    "title": "List Jobs",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Jobs/",
        "children": "List Jobs"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },
  
  {
    "key": "Config.Category.List",
    "title": "List Categories",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Config/Category/",
        "children": "List Categories"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Config.Specialist.List",
    "title": "List Specialists",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Config/Specialist/",
        "children": "List Specialists"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "Config.Status.List",
    "title": "List Statuses",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/Config/Status/",
        "children": "List Statuses"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  }, 
  {
    "key": "UserManagement.List",
    "title": "List Users",
    "component": {
      "type": {},
      "key": null,
      "ref": null,
      "props": {
        "to": "/admin/UserManagement/",
        "children": "List Users"
      },
      "_owner": null,
      "_store": {}
    }
  }
]
```

At present I have the following which works for the 1st level objects, but the sub menu's all get returned:

```
const MenuSearch = (value) => {
        const SearchTerm = value.toLowerCase();
        console.log(SearchTerm, MenuItems);
        if (!value || value.length < 1){
            // show all menu items
            SetMenuItemsFiltered(MenuItems);   
        } else {
            let temp = [...MenuItems];

            SetMenuItemsFiltered(temp.filter((MenuItem) => {
                if (!MenuItem.isSubMenu && !MenuItem.isDivider){
                    return MenuItem.title.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm);
                } else if (MenuItem.isSubMenu){
                    return MenuItem.submenus.filter((SubMenuItem) => {
                        const SubMenuItemLabel = SubMenuItem.title.toLowerCase();
                        console.log(SubMenuItemLabel, SearchTerm, SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm))
                        return SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm.toLowerCase());
                    })
                }
            }));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to filter the objects by them selves, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `~` in `!~value.length` is just my preferred way to say "don't start from -1 and consider it 0"

```js
const MenuSearch = (value) => {
  const searchWord = value.toLowerCase();

  if (!value || !~value.length) {
    // early return.
    return SetMenuItemsFiltered(MenuItems);
  }

  const result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const title = curr.title?.toLowerCase();

    if (!curr.submenus && !curr.isDivider) {
      if (title.includes(searchWord)) {
        return prev.concat(curr);
      }
    }

    if (curr.isSubMenu) {
      return prev.concat(
        curr.submenus.filter((item) =>
          item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
        ),
      );
    }

    return prev;
  }, []);

  SetMenuItemsFiltered(result);
};
```

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
const objectsFilter = require("objectsfilter");
const data = require("./data.json");

const MenuSearch = (value) => {
  const searchWord = value.toLowerCase();

  if (!value || !~value.length) {
    // early return.
    return SetMenuItemsFiltered(MenuItems);
  }

  const result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => {
    const title = curr.title?.toLowerCase();

    if (!curr.submenus && !curr.isDivider) {
      if (title.includes(searchWord)) {
        return prev.concat(curr);
      }
    }

    if (curr.isSubMenu) {
      const submenus = [];

      objectsFilter.objectsForEach(curr, (currentItem, key) => {
        if (key === "submenus") {
          submenus.push(
            currentItem.filter((item) =>
              item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchWord)
            ),
          );
        }
      });

      return prev.concat({
        ...curr,
        submenus,
      });
    }

    return prev;
  }, []);


  SetMenuItemsFiltered(result);
};
```

Objectsfilter: https://github.com/Meno-101/objectsfilter

npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/objectsfilter

Comment: Interesting but how would this work with the above nested objects?

Comment: you want everything that has the value "list" right?

Comment: Yep so it should reaturn anything that matches list

Comment: Give me two or three minutes

Comment: Considering your answer, I've found I was reading the question wrong. I've improved your answer a bit; hence I found it a little to complicated, please allow me to update my answer in a bit.

Comment: can you explain the `title?`

Comment: oh yes this is a feature in typescript, been added recently to nodejs, it just means `curr.title && curr.title.toLowerCase()`

Comment: And I think I found yet a better answer

Comment: I found a bug, fixed., btw you can use `Object.keys` instead of the npm module I made, not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are filtering the `MenuItem.submenus` but not storing the values filtered. Instead, you are just returning the whole `MenuItem.submenu`

So It should be

```
MenuItem.submenus= MenuItem.submenus.filter((SubMenuItem) => { 
  const SubMenuItemLabel = SubMenuItem.title.toLowerCase(); 
  return SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm.toLowerCase());
 })
```

and return true if `MenuItem.submenus.length>0`.

So final code would be

```
 temp.filter((MenuItem) => {
   if (!MenuItem.isSubMenu && !MenuItem.isDivider){
       return MenuItem.title.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm);
   } else if (MenuItem.isSubMenu){
       MenuItem.submenus= MenuItem.submenus.filter((SubMenuItem) => {
         const SubMenuItemLabel = SubMenuItem.title.toLowerCase();
         console.log(SubMenuItemLabel, SearchTerm, 
         SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm))
         return SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm.toLowerCase());
        })
     return MenuItem.submenus.length;
   }
})
```

Comment: thanks for this but I'm still getting the same issue where items not containing "list" are being returned

Comment: When I tried assigning temp.filter() to a variable and setMenuItemFiltered(thatVariable) it works. But when the whole function is inside serMenuItemFiltered() like in your code, it doesnt filter properly.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a different approach with this, rather than returning on the filter I would use the filter to create a new array of objects that matched.  I've posted the answer here but will continue to check if anyone comes up with a better solution.

```
const MenuSearch = (value) => {
        const SearchTerm = value.toLowerCase();
        if (!value || value.length < 1){
            // show all menu items
            SetMenuItemsFiltered(MenuItems);   
        } else {
            let FilteredItems = [];

            // filter the data
            MenuItems.filter((MenuItem) => {
                if (!MenuItem.isSubMenu && !MenuItem.isDivider){
                    if (MenuItem.title.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm)){
                        FilteredItems.push(MenuItem);
                    }
                    //return MenuItem.title.toLowerCase().includes(SearchTerm);
                } else if (MenuItem.isSubMenu){
                    MenuItem.submenus.filter((SubMenuItem) => {
                        const SubMenuItemLabel = SubMenuItem.title.toLowerCase();
                        // return SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm);
                        if (SubMenuItemLabel.includes(SearchTerm)){
                            FilteredItems.push(SubMenuItem);
                        }
                    })
                }
            });

            SetMenuItemsFiltered(FilteredItems);
        }
    }
```